# how to multiple update rows from java to sql

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I have this part of the code

```
try
 {
  Connection conn=new DBconnect().con();
   Statement stmt=new DBconnect().stm(conn);
   //Statement stmt2=new DBconnect().stm(conn);
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "UPDATE bill SET     REMAIND_FREE_TIME="+FreeTimeN+"WHERE telephone="+tel);
// ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(" UPDATE bill SET REMAIND_FREE_TIME="+FreeTimeN2+"WHERE telephone="+tel2);
```

The thing is that whenever I run it with the one update everything goes fine but when I run both of them it makes mistake.And this is the databaase class:

```
package database_console;

 import frames.login;
import java.sql.*;

public class DBconnect {
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
Connection conn;

public Connection con() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
Class.forName( "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" ) ;

    // Get a connection to the database
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@83.212.240.15:1521:orcl","it21119", "a37161637" ) ;
    return conn;
}

public Statement stm(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    // Get a statement from the connection
   stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
return stmt;
}


public void stop(Connection conn,Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{

    rs.close() ;
  stmt.close() ;
  conn.close() ;
 }
}
```

Any suggestions?Thx in advance.(btw I am using sqldeveloper with ojdbc6.jar)

Comment: What "mistake" does it make? Is there an error?

Comment: If I run both updates, the second update in the //comment will update the first tel not the tel2 with the FreeTimeN2.It's a mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only problem can be the parameters you are passing are not Varchar2 columns in database.

Better use `PreparedStatement` and set parameters. Check this link for details on `PreparedStatement`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html